# VS Code Python Unit Test tool partially listing unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VS Code Unit Test tool, which cannot list all the unit tests shown below:

[image]

The error in Output -> Python is below:

> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe ~.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.16.0\pythonFiles\testing_tools\unittest_discovery.py . test_*.py
> cwd: .
> [ERROR 2023-5-9 10:30:10.806]: Error discovering unittest tests:
> Failed to import test module: DownloadFromADCOrchestrator
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 470, in _find_test_path
> package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
> File "C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in *get_module_from_name
> **import**(name)
> File "c:\Users\tom\repos\Rlam.DataPlatform.FunctionApp.PythonEtl\DownloadFromADCOrchestrator_*init**.py", line 12, in 
> import azure.functions as func
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'

Below is in the requirements.txt

azure-functions

azure.storage.blob

azure.identity

azure-functions-durable==1.1.6

Comment: Did you make sure you have chosen the right Python interpreter in VS Code?

Comment: yes, I did. It can partially discover unit tests, which means the right Python interpreter is selected.

Comment: No, it does not mean that at all. Don't make assumptions - verify.

Comment: Have you read [the document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_test-discovery) and performed it correctly

Answer (score 0):

If a python file containing test code crashes when run, this can prevent subsequent tests from being discovered.

In VS Code, manually run each of your python test files and look for one that crashes when run